# Is there a way to make vertical spacing equal programmatically for button controls?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I know there is a way to make spacing equal for controls in the designer view. But is this possible to do it programatically? Because I have a form with multiple buttons and we dont know which buttons will be displayed and which will be hidden at the compile time. So they look uneven when the form is displayed(some with more spacing and some with less spacing). Is there a way to re position them at the run time? Is there an equivalent to doing the Format -> Horizontal Spacing -> Make equal programatically?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you could add them to a TableLayoutPanel

Comment: Anything that can be done in the designer can be done through code.

Comment: Why not put the buttons in `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it using [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Which represents a panel that dynamically lays out its contents horizontally or vertically.

`When all the buttons are visible`
[image: When all the buttons are visible]

`When button3 is hidden at runtime`
[image: When button3 is hidden at runtime]